# python convert chinese characters in url

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I have a url like

**href="../job/jobarea.asp?C_jobtype=經營管理主管&peoplenumber=151"**,

this is shown in inspect element.
But when opened in new tab it is showing as

**../job/jobarea.asp?C_jobtype=%B8g%C0%E7%BA%DE%B2z%A5D%BA%DE&peoplenumber=151**

How do I know which type of encoding is used by the browser to convert it. When I try to do scrapy it is showing some other format and it is stopping as 500 internal server error. Could you please explain me??

Comment: Does the HTML page have any `<meta>` headers that set the page codec? There could also be a content type set in the HTTP headers (`Content-Type: text/html; charset=....`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters    The page has only headers like:`Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:case_noteice=mycase; myjobcrm=crmid=myjob; connother%5Fdb=DB1; connjob%5Fdb=DB2; ASPSESSIONIDASARCSTS=MJGFLIOCJADBKKMKMFDEIPNA
Host:www.myjob.com.tw
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36`

Comment: It'll have a `Content-Type` header too. The browser uses a `charset` parameter in that header if no characterset has been defined in the page itself.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Response Headers contain 
`Content-Type:text/html` , In response page it contains as `charset=big5`

Comment: @MartijnPieters Got the solution.. In response page it contains `charset=big5` so used @Aaron solution and got the url as it is.  Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Tradtional Chinese, so try `cp950`

```
#-*-coding:utf8 -*-

import urllib
s = '經營管理主管'.decode('utf-8').encode('cp950')
print urllib.quote(s)

q ='%B8g%C0%E7%BA%DE%B2z%A5D%BA%DE'
print urllib.unquote(q).decode('cp950').encode('utf-8')
```

Result

```
%B8g%C0%E7%BA%DE%B2z%A5D%BA%DE
經營管理主管
```

Comment: @philshem, i need it in python 2.7

Comment: @Aaron, Super thing. Loved it.  But the point is when I do it this way, I am getting 404 page unresponsive... This is the url I am able to print to console...  **u'../job/jobarea.asp?C_jobtype=\u7d93\u71df\u7ba1\u7406\u4e3b\u7ba1&peoplenumber
=151'**

Comment: What is the full url you want to get?

Comment: @Aaron, I am getting a url like this when I write xpaths.....**u'../job/jobarea.asp?C_jobtype=\u7d93\u71df\u7ba1\u7406\u4e3b\u7ba1&peoplenumbe‌​r =151'** .... This is the original url I should be getting on redirecting.... **'%B8g%C0%E7%BA%DE%B2z%A5D%BA%DE'**, this is the original one shown in website.  [website_link](http://www.myjob.com.tw/job/jobzone.asp)

Comment: @Aaron , Thank you so much. Got the solution. In response page `charset=big5` is present. So in place of `.encode('cp950')` I have given `big5` and got the correct output now. Thank you so much